# Жизнь Service Android

Tags: android, websocket, service, уведомления

разрабатываю приложение Android, где есть служба, в которой реализован WebSocket (okhttp),то есть пока служба запущена, я могу постучаться и отослать пакет на приложение(Notification), служба Липкая,при destroy возобновляется и заново открывается SOCKET. Когда смартфон включен то все хорошо, стоит ему побыть в спящем режиме, все отваливается и SOCKET и служба. Читал множество статей и форумов, где грешат на Android защиту батареи и памяти, мол убивает ОС процесс,когда ей необходимо. Вопрос, как мне побороть. Ведь например WatsApp и Viber ,даже когда телефон наглухо во сне отсылают Notification???

Comment: жизненный вопрос! Не могли бы в конце привести реализация тела своего сервис (+ инициализацию)

Comment: Push Notifications делаются с использованием [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/)

Answer (score 1):

Метод `startForeground` должен уберечь ваш сервис от убийства его системой. [Из документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service?hl=ru#startForeground(int,%20android.app.Notification)):

> If your service is started (running through
>   Context.startService(Intent)), then also make this service run in the
>   foreground, supplying the ongoing notification to be shown to the user
>   while in this state. By default started services are background,
>   meaning that their process won't be given foreground CPU scheduling
>   (unless something else in that process is foreground) and, if the
>   system needs to kill them to reclaim more memory (such as to display a
>   large page in a web browser), they can be killed without too much
>   harm. You use startForeground(int, Notification) if killing your
>   service would be disruptive to the user, such as if your service is
>   performing background music playback, so the user would notice if
>   their music stopped playing.

Comment: ух, вы мне здорово подсказали)

Comment: startForeground Попробую,но пока логически не ясно,как Notification и его запизивание с id в startForeground метод сделает службу передним планом

Comment: @ALEX123, термин "передний план" (foreground) не значит, что служба работает в главном потоке. Но "это означает, что система присвоит службе наивысший приоритет, и поэтому служба не является кандидатом для удаления системой в случае нехватки памяти".

Comment: Спасибо всем!Все работает как и хотел, но теперь следующий вопрос! Когда пользователь блокирует уведомление моего приложения, как мне запустить процесс заново, когда человек поставит обратно что разрешить уведомления?То есть захотел выключил-процесс умер, захотел включил разрешение уведомления-процесс возобновился или запустился вновь!

Comment: startForeground и Notification я запихнул в onCreate() сервиса!!